# WebFlux and Kotlin use ReactiveCrudRepository in multimodule application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I have an example SpringBoot app in Kotlin and WebFlux. I divided whole application into modules (as I'm used to from asp.net).

Modules:

- core (models, DTO, helpers, etc...) referenced everywhere
- data (repositories, tables...) referenced only in business
- business (services, handlers...) referenced in api
- api actual SpringBoot application

My problem now is how to properly work with ReactiveCrudRepository<> and repositories in general. I have config class in data module to enable R2dbcRepositories.

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories("me.janam.data")
open class RepositoriesConfiguration {
}
```

Now if I create table and repository

```
interface IPersonRepository: ReactiveCrudRepository<PersonTable, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person.person limit 1")
    fun getOne(): Mono<PersonTable>
}
```

and try to use it in business module I'm getting an error

```
Cannot access 'org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository' which is a supertype of 'me.janam.data.features.person.repositories.IPersonRepository'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

Of course if I add

```
implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6")
```

into my business module everything works fine. But somehow this feels strange to me. Is this the right way how to do this?

Also not part of my main question but here is complete config and I like to hear some opinion on it as i'm mainly asp.net dev. Thx.

root - settings.gradle.kts:

```
rootProject.name = "springboot-example"
include(":api")
include(":business")
include(":data")
include(":core")
```

root - gradle.properties:

```
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin_version=1.4.31
kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version=1.4.3

r2dbc_postgresql_version=0.8.7.RELEASE
postgresql_version=42.2.19

spring_context_version=5.3.5
```

root - build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.31"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management" )

    dependencyManagement {
        
    }
}

group = "me.janam"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.5")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "13"
}
```

core - build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "me.janam"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "13"
}
```

data - build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version: String by project
val r2dbc_postgresql_version: String by project
val postgresql_version: String by project
val spring_context_version: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "me.janam"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))

    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:$spring_context_version")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc:2.4.4")
    runtimeOnly("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql:$r2dbc_postgresql_version")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresql_version")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:$kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version")

    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "13"
}
```

business - build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version: String by project
val spring_context_version: String by project

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

group = "me.janam"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":data"))

    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:$spring_context_version")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:$kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version")

    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6") //TODO

    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>() {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "13"
}
```

api - build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.4"
    // Přesunuto do rootu
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.31"
}

group = "me.janam"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
//java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":core"))
    implementation(project(":business"))

    //implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    //runtimeOnly("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-postgresql")
    //runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "13"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Your api module needs to properly find all `@Configuration` annotated classes during startup. `@SpringBootApplication` is a combination of multiple annotations, and one of them is `@ComponentScan` so if my guess i right you must use that annotation on your main method and in that declare all packages that will contain any type of bean (annotated classes like @Configuration, @Controller @Service etc.) so that the application can scan all these packages for beans to run during startup.

Comment: You see the default behaviour is that spring will scan all subdirectories from the main class location to find beans, but you have placed them in seperate modules.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Hi, I think that registering in DI is not a problem. Problem is that business module doesn't know ReactiveCrudRepository<> interface and I do not know if adding implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6") which contains ReactiveCrudRepository<> interface into business module is good practice. Or Am I missing something? :( Thx for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the same set of dependencies to each subproject may feel odd, but it's totally fine to do. In order to use a given dependency in a given subproject, you'll have to specify it as a dependency for that subproject.

There are, however, neater ways to accomplish this than actually copy-pasting the import statement to each build file. I would suggest specifying a `subprojects` section in your root `build.gradle.kts` and putting shared & common dependencies there:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        // Put items here that are used in all/most subprojects:
        implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:$spring_context_version")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:$kotlinx_coroutines_reactor_version")

        // You can put this import here or just keep it in the build files
        // for subprojects where it will actually get used
        implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6")

        testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
    }
}
```

You'll still need to specify in each sub-build file what other subprojects each depends on with `implementation(project(":core"))` type statements, but the above `dependencies` block takes care of making the specified libraries accessible in all subprojects.